# The Derivation of Gaussian Process Posterior

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, gaussian-process

Denote the training data and training target as $X, y$, respectively, now we aim at applying the Gaussian process (GP) for regression. Here, we assume the prior is a GP:
$$
p(f(X)) = \mathcal{GP}(m(X), K(X,X)),
$$
where $m(\cdot)$ is the mean function and $K(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the covariance matrix with $K$ denoting kernel function. The likelihood is defined as
$$
p(y | f, X) = \mathcal{N}(y | f(X), \sigma^2 I).
$$
Then, based on the conjugate property of GP prior, the posterior can be derived as
$$
p(f(X_{*}) | y, X) = \mathcal{GP}(m_{post}(X_* ), K_{post}(X_*, X_*)),
$$
$$
m_{post}(X_*) = m(X_*) + K(X_*, X)(K(X,X)+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}(y - m(X)),
$$
$$
K_{post}(X_*, X_*) = K(X_*, K_*) - K(X_*, X)(K(X,X)+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}K(X, X_*).
$$
This is the final expression of GP regression (we call it **method 1**). Alternatively, we can arrive at the same result in another way (we call it **method 2**), as shown in the following:

We define the joint probability of the function of observed&unobserved data as a GP
$$
p(f, f_* | X, X_*) = \mathcal{N}\left( \left[\begin{array}{c}
m(X)\\ m(X_*)  \end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{cc}
K(X,X) & K(K, K_* )\\
K(X_*, X) & K(X_*, X_*) 
\end{array}\right]\right),
$$
where $X_*$ denotes the unobserved data. Then the conditional probability of $f_*$ is given by
$$
p(f_* | f, X, X_*) = \mathcal{N}( \mathbb{E}[f_* | f, X, X_*], \mathbb{V}[f_* | f, X, X_*]),
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}[f_* | f, X, X_*] = m(X_*) + K(X_*, X)(K(X,X)+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}(y - m(X)),
$$
$$
\mathbb{V}[f_* | f, X, X_*] = K(X_*, K_*) - K(X_*, X)(K(X,X)+\sigma^2 I)^{-1}K(X, X_*).
$$

---

Obviously, the results of method 1&2 are the same. I can understand method 1 because it is a formal Bayesian perspective. But what is the intuition behind method 2? It seems quite simple than method 1, but it gives the same result. Why does it work? I mean simply given a prior of the joint distribution, and the answer automatedly arises in the posterior. Could anybody give me an intuitive explanation?

PS: I follow the notation of GP in the lecture of Marc Deisenroth. The GP formula in this question is at 1:07:07 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdCXdUzLfao), in which you can fully understand the derivation of these two methods.

Comment: Something seems off here. You describe method 1 as producing $p(f_* \mid X, y)$ (looks like you forgot to condition on $X_*$ too). This would be the posterior predictive distribution of the latent function values at $X_*$, given the training set $(X,y)$. In contrast, you describe method 2 as producing $p(f_* \mid f, X, X_*)$. This is a different object than in method 1. It's the posterior predictive distribution of the latent function outputs at $X_*$, given observations of $X$ and $f$. But, according to your model, $f$ is latent and only $y$ is observed, so why condition on $f$?

Comment: Finally, the expressions you write in method $2$ depend on $y$ and $\sigma^2$, which doesn't make sense if you're conditioning on $f$ and not $y$. It looks like your original intent for method 2 might've been something along the lines of equations 2.18 and/or 2.21 in [GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf)?